# Can oxygen form six bonds

Tags: coordination-compounds

Oxygen is a small size atom known to make only two bonds (sigma bonds), it may also form coordination bonds {oxygen ion (2-) uses its outer shell in coordination (only s & p orbitals) that theoretically form a maximum of four bonds}.
In the decavanadate ion cluster (V10O28)6-, there are oxygen atoms with one bond, two bonds, three bonds and six bonds. Can anyone explain how oxygen can bridges 3 and 6 atoms in this structure

Comment: There were numerous theoretical investigations on this polyoxometalate, and most of the point to these six bonds having ionic nature. Once this is proved, there is no element of surprise anymore.

Comment: I would suggest to draw an image of the cluster using any CIF and post V−O bond lengths to better illustrate your question.

Comment: The V-O distance varies in literature, almost 2.1077 - 2.3382 Å

Comment: It is also drawn as a solid line in all crystal structures, I believe no solid line between the atoms should be drawn if it is ionic

Comment: +1 for element of surprise. Perhaps a stable transuranic?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/121196/why-cant-o-form-of6